# I am trying to generate a variable on page load which I then want to guess multiple times, how do I stop variable from refreshing with each guess?

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple number guessing game. I would like multiple attempts so I have taken the random number generator outisde of an onclick function assuming that this would make my number "stick" however I am still having the random variable refresh every attempt. Why is this happening?

```
<p>Guess a number</p>

<form><input type="text" id="guess"><button id="guessbutton">Guess</button></form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var numberwang = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

    console.log(numberwang);

    document.getElementById("guessbutton").onclick = function() {

        if (document.getElementById("guess").value == numberwang) {

            alert("That's numberwang!")

        } else {

            alert("That's not numberwang, try again")

        }

    }

</script>
```

Using the console I can see that the number refreshes with each attempt. I was under the impression that having the code inside only the script tags meant that the number would only be generated on page load. Is this not the case? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no need to wrap the button in a `<form>`, and removing it will stop the button from sending the form, which is what refreshes the page (a form without attributes defaults to `method="get" action=""` which will reload the page)

Comment: localStorage is a 3rd potential solution. it allows you to persist data between page loads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stop the default behaviour of the button inside the form, which is to submit the form and this refreshes the page. See below:

```
<p>Guess a number</p>

<form><input type="text" id="guess"><button id="guessbutton">Guess</button></form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var numberwang = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

    console.log(numberwang);

    document.getElementById("guessbutton").onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (document.getElementById("guess").value == numberwang) {

            alert("That's numberwang!")

        } else {

            alert("That's not numberwang, try again")

        }

    }

</script>
```

e.preventDefault() will stop any default behaviour of any dom element. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: you should try to make it more clear that the solution is `e.preventDefault()` instead of just providing the code.

Comment: @JohnSonnino No problem. Could you please accept the answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your numbers using the [browser storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem):

```
storage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);
```

Example:

```
localStorage.setItem('randomNumber1', getRandomNumber());
localStorage.setItem('randomNumber2', getRandomNumber());
localStorage.setItem('randomNumber3', getRandomNumber());
localStorage.setItem('randomNumber4', getRandomNumber());


function getRandomNumber(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
}
```

And acces the numbers with:

```
localStorage.getItem('randomNumber1');
localStorage.getItem('randomNumber2');
localStorage.getItem('randomNumber3');
localStorage.getItem('randomNumber4');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `evt.preventDefault()` should do the trick.
The `preventDefault()` method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur.

For example, this can be useful when:

- Clicking on a "Submit" button, prevent it from submitting a form
- Clicking on a link, prevent the link from following the URL.

Try the code below.

```
<p>Guess a number</p>
<form><input type="text" id="guess"><button id="guessbutton">Guess</button></form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var numberwang = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    console.log(numberwang);
    document.getElementById("guessbutton").onclick = function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        if (document.getElementById("guess").value == numberwang) {
            alert("That's numberwang!")
        } else {
            alert("That's not numberwang, try again")
        }
    }
</script>
```